# Protected Router Outlet in new Router-angular2

Tags: angular

Hello in the deprecated ng2 routes i have used a protected outlet which navigates to a component only when the user is authenticated.But in new router i am not finding anyone speaking about protected routes.Everyone are using canActivate guard when defining their routes in `app.routing.ts` file. I feel that rather than defining canActivate guard for route in my route definitions having a protected outlet seems to be an easy way.

```
@Directive({
selector: 'protected-router-outlet',
})
export class ProtectedOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
private parentRouter: Router;
publicRoutes: any;
constructor(_viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader, _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string, private auth: AuthService) {
    super(_viewContainer, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
    this.publicRoutes = {
        '/Login': true
    };
}
  activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    var url = this.parentRouter.lastNavigationAttempt;
    var LoggedIn = this.auth.IsLoggedIn();
    if (!LoggedIn) {
        this.parentRouter.navigateByUrl('/Login');
    }
    return super.activate(instruction);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to have a protected outlet in new Router.If yes how can i use protected outlets because i cant find `ComponentInstruction` in new routes.
can someone please help me out.If i am wrong please suggest me with the correct approach to protect a route.Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `CanActivate` guards?

Comment: Because i should define for every route which is defined. I am not against `CanActivate`. But rather than defining `canActivate` i thought having protected outlet is easy to use.Even if i forget to mention the `canActivate` the protected outlet handles that so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If specifying the AuthGuard for every route is too cumbersome, you can do this:

```
const unprotectedRoutes = [];
const protectedRoutes = [
  // protected routes here
].map((r:Route) => {
  r.canActivate = (r.canActivate) ? [AuthGuard, ...r.canActivate] : [AuthGuard];
  return r;
});

export const routeConfig = [...unprotectedRoutes, ...protectedRoutes];
```

I'm using this to add a "LogGuard" (which doesn't actually guard anything, but logs navigation) to all of my routes.